# Is there a way to submit data to google forms, but not redirect to the google form?

Tags: javascript, google-forms

I'm new to javascript, and I'm working on a project to accept data from a  and then output the data to google forms cuz idk how to host my own server. However, I don't want to be redirected to google forms. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

While creating the Google Form, go to the Settings bar and enable the "Allow only one response per user" option. When the unique option for a Google Form is enabled, respondents must sign in with their Google account to access the form.

hope this helps.

Comment: I think you understood my question wrong. I asked is there a way to submit data to google forms without having javascript open the form to submit

Answer (score 0):

Create a form with same input names as google form and submit the response to google form api.